# Independence Number Proof Explanation

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, coloring

In the following proof it states that "$v_i$ is less than or equal to the independence number for all $i$." Why is this true?

[image]

I know what an independence number represents, I am struggling to eloquently explain why this is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the graph independence number $\beta(G)$ is the size of its maximum independent set. When the graph is colored with $\chi(G)$ colors, then each set of its vertices of a single color is also independent set - so, the size of each such set (denoted here by $V_i$) is less than or equal to size of the maximum independent set (because it's the maximum).

The inequality below shows the complete proof:

$$n = \sum_{i=1}^{\chi(G)}V_i \le \beta(G)\chi(G)$$